# Deploy a TCP Server written in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, nginx, deployment, tcp

I've written a TCP Server in ruby running on port 2000 with event machine.

Right now, what I do is ssh to my server and run the command `ruby lib/tcp_server.rb` to turn on the server, but it shuts down when I log out.

I've tried nohup and using `&` but nothing seems to stick for the server for a long time.

So my question is, how do I deploy this server on port 2000 and keep it running, like how we deploy Rails to nginx.

It's not a webserver, but an a tcp server for a connected device, if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to **daemonize** your ruby script.

Comment: @pascalbetz Yeah I got that from reading, and thought putting `&` at the end of the command ought to do it, but it doesn't. How do you suggest daemonizing it?

Comment: You could either use a gem like [daemons](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons) to make the script daemonize itself or an external utility like [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) that can daemonize (and manage) arbitrary scripts.

Comment: @Shobhit please try one of the solutions proposed by Stefan. Should you have any problems then you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Have used `Process.daemon` for now which works, but doesn't start the server if the machine restarts, or the process is killed.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: `tmux` or `screen`

This is the simplest way to approach, you will have to create a tmux or screen session, then start your server in that session.

Solution 2: `nohup`

```
nohup ruby lib/tcp_server.rb > stdout.log 2> stderr.log &
```

You've tried `nohup` and using `&`, I suppose you've already known how to do.

Solution 3: daemonize

You can detach from the shell and daemonize the process by forking 
it twice, setting the session ID and changing the current working directory.

```
def daemonize
  exit if fork
  Process.setsid
  exit if fork
  Dir.chdir '/'
end
```

With this approach, you will have to redirect stdout and stderr to keep logs.

Another way to daemonize is to use gems like [daemons](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons).

update:

To restart the process automatically after being killed, you need a process manager like [god](https://github.com/mojombo/god) or [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

To start the process automatically after booting, you need to compose an [init scripts](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Init) but how it looks like depends on your service management system and operating system. One of the most well-known is System V. If you are using Ubuntu, you might want to take a look at [Upstart](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Upstart) or [systemd](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Systemd).

Comment: Yes, I've done these, the thing is I need to start them again if the server restarts, and the process doesn't restart itself if killed.